# Cartoon episode aired in the eighties featuring underwater dry land and a suspended water ceiling sustained by volcanoes

Tags: cartoon, episode-identification, hanna-barbera

I remember watching a certain US cartoon episode in the middle eighties in Brazil as a kid. Possibly a Godzilla,  Sealab 2020, Johnny Quest or similar Hanna-Barbera cartoon featuring ocean waters. As usual in  this kind of question, I can remember very little of it.

Human protagonists were trapped in a submarine location which featured dry land and an atmosphere. The characters perceived the sky as sea water which would not fall over them, impeded from doing so by some unknown force.

At a certain point one of the characters noticed and informed others that this was caused by some kind of bubbly upward flow (air, water? Lava? No, I don't think it was red) springing from one or more underwater volcanoes, which prevented the 'sky' from collapsing.

Possibly (I can't remember for sure, so don't take much of this in consideration) the region featured strange flora/fauna (perhaps dinosaurs or something similar), and (another thing that may have come out of my imagination) the whole region was destroyed in the end when the volcano(es) ceased to function; the characters escaped as usual, and the region could not be visited again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds the animated Tarzan series could go on your list of possible sources. By which I mean *Tarzan, Lord of the Jungle*, not the later one.

Comment: Indeed! According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarzan,_Lord_of_the_Jungle) it could be season 2 episode _"Tarzan and the Sunken City of Atlantis"_. Too bad I couldn't find any YouTube videos.  but thanks a lot for the hint, from the episode descriptions you can tell _Tarzan_ was, as we say here, a crazy show, with Vikings, robots, UFOs, dinosaurs, and whatnot. 

Comment: Too bad, it isn't it. Just checked a downloaded ep. Nice try, though. It isn't _Tarzan at the Earth's Core_ from the 1st season nor _Tarzan and the Lost World_ from the 3rd season either.